# A way to return empty query in Laravel local scopes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using local scopes in my models in my app to 'filter' allowed models on the index page. If the user doesn't have permission to index models, that scope should return an empty query, and at the ending, it should return an empty result.

```
public function scopeViewable($query, User $user)
{
    if ($user->can('bills.index'))
    {
        return $query->whereIn('location_id', $user->shopAccess->location_ids);
    }

    // return empty query
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to return empty queries than

```
return $query->where('id', null)
```

Because this model has id as the primary key, it cannot be null, and this will return an empty query, but it can be pretty inefficient. Also, is there something better to limit indexing?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve here, normally if a user tries to do something they are not allowed you'd throw an unauthorised exception via e.g. `abort(403)` or something like that .

Comment: Trying to simplify authorization for what user is allowed (first if it is allowed to see anything) to see on index page. The only thing I know is to check for index permission and in the body to do call scope method. I thought that it is possible to achieve this with less code in index method of controller. @apokryfos

Comment: Still throwing an exception when a user is not allowed to do anything and catching it at the place you are populating the view is probably easiest